# Disable HideBottomViewOnScrollBehaviour

Tags: android, scroll, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

I currently have a bottom navigation bar inside a Coordinator layout, which I added a HideBottomViewOnScrollBehaviour to. Some screens require the navigation bar to be hidden, which I can achieve by calling the slideUp / slideDown methods from the `behaviour` object of BottomNavigationBar layout params.

The issue is, even if i'm hiding it programatically, you can reveal it by simply scrolling up again.

I didn't find any solutions, i was thinking there will be something like disabling the behaviour and enabling it on certain screens, but that's not a thing.

Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps add `position: fixed` to the scrollbar?

Comment: did my answer help you? please accept it if it did.

Comment: @VasiliyT did not have time to try it yet. Dont worry i will accept it if it's the case.

Answer (score 2):

Here are methods to disable/enable scrolling behaviour:

```
fun enableLayoutBehaviour() {
    val params = navView?.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
    if (params.behavior == null) {
        params.behavior = HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior<View>()
    }
    navView?.let {
        (params.behavior as HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior).slideUp(it)
    }
}

fun disableLayoutBehaviour() {
    val params = navView?.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
    navView?.let {
        (params.behavior as HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior).slideDown(it)
    }
    params.behavior = null
}
```

You can also just replace NestedScrollView with regular ScrollView on dedicated tabs to disable bottom bar from scrolling.

Comment: i managed to disable it, but the bottom view is not sliding up again when i enable the layoutBehaviour again. Any suggestions to this?

Comment: I just created a custom behaviour that enables/disables itself. Thanks anyway for your help!